# Nested table like macos file explorer

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to figure out how to make a table like in the picture below of the macos file explorer.  I want to be able to show one record per file but in a nested list tree view with columns for properties for each file.

My initial thought was a nested ul or table in side of the first column of each record but this did not work obviously it just showed the list and they shared the columns.

So the question is what is the best approach to creating a table like this in html/css?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered an [_accordion_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accordion) approach? :)

Comment: @MattAllegro i have not.  I had no idea where to start lol.  This should give me a good hook to start researching thank you!